# How to get just first three parts of a ip address in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

How to get just first three parts of a IP address in red shift for example if its 1.2.3.4 I only need 1.2.3

i have tried regexp_substr(email,'.[^.]*') which returns the first part only

Answer (score 3):

you can use split_part function,

```
select split_part(ip,'.',1)||'.'||split_part(ip,'.',2)||'.'||split_part(ip,'.',3)
```